# Joomla! 2.5 - Implement custom table as plugin or module?

Tags: php, html, joomla

Just started developing with Joomla! (2.5), completely newb, read through the docs talking about Plugins, Components and Modules. Having a hard time figuring out which to choose and how to implement. I'd like to have a table similar to the one used in the Plugin Manager in the Joomla! administrator backend where the the results can be searched, filtered and even individual entries can be toggled (Enable/Disable by clicking on Status circle). Can someone point me to a tutorial or even some example code I can in developing this?

I’ve already read a few sites including this (http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/joomla-25/plugin-vs-module-vs-component).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create page in administrator panel with tables, that display some items, you should develop joomla component.
Look for this: http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!2.5

Note, that only components can provide extended administrator interface for managing some entries, create pages on font-end. Plugins intended only for processing output of components and modules. And modules intended only for display some html on specific positions in front-end template.

Comment: Thanks,  that helps. So the Plugin Manager is really a component? How do i know what component is being used in the plugin manager?